# Add placeholder to file name without being a chunked key?

Tags: fluentd

I'm currently using fluentd to write out log messages to a file with the `file` output plugin. Is there a way to use a field in the log message as a placeholder in the file name without specificing it as a chunked key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can not.

https://docs.fluentd.org/output/file

https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section